# Can’t run a single flatpak app

Tags: flatpak

Every flatpak app fails with this message:

```
$ flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox 
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
error: ldconfig failed, exit status 256
```

It must be something with bubblewrap or with the way it’s used, because:

```
$ bwrap 
bwrap: Unexpected capabilities but not setuid, old file caps config?
$ sudo bwrap 
usage: bwrap [OPTIONS...] [--] COMMAND [ARGS...]

    --help                       Print this help
    --version                    Print version
    ...
```